# Drupal 7 form, query DB and results display

Tags: 7

I'm still somewhat new to Drupal but have a lot of experience programming in PHP. I'm looking for a list of modules in Drupal. I need to do this common list of tasks that are very typical of DB interaction:

1. Present a form to a user.
2. Do a query (select or insert) to one or many tables in a database in a custom DB or the one Drupal uses/
3. Present results in table form.

Please help me out thanks. Could anybody can give a sample examples.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need. Take a look into the [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module. And [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) of course. No need for handcrafted SQL.

Comment: Please provide me a sample examples.

Comment: Please look into the Examples Module. There are in there.